# Http post add data to request

Tags: android, json, post, http-post

i want to send data like :

```
 subscription = [{
          "category":"news", 
          "content_id","id ",  
          },]
```

To Url `subscribe/?=authparams{"token":"1652d47b7c16da74e5d021510e441f49", “action”:”set”}`

How can I make it? I try next, but it did not work for me.

```
  String xml = "authparams={\"token\":\"" + token + "\",\"action\":\"" + "set"+ "\"}";
        // Creating HTTP client
        String subs="subscription =[{\"category\":\"posts\"," +
                "\"content_id\",\""+id+"\",}]";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://site.co/api/subscribe/");
        // Url Encoding the POST parameters
        try {
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(subs.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.d("myLogs:", EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<NameValuePair> submit_data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
submit_data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", "news");
submit_data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content_id", "id");

String response = "";

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost http_client = new HttpPost("http://site.co/api/subscribe?authparams[token]=1652d47b7c16da74e5d021510e441f49&authparams[action]=set");
try {
    http_client.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(submit_data));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(http_client);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    Log.d("myLogs:", EntityUtils.toString(entity));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can you show me how should i edit my code with your?

Comment: I already have except the url.. is the authparams in get? and `subscribe/?=authparams{"token":"1652d47b7c16da74e5d021510e441f49", “action”:”set”}` is not a std. url how are you receiving them at server? are they like `authparams[token]` and `authparams[action]`?

Comment: yes, they like authparams[token] and authparams[action]

Comment: Should i add two Entities?

Comment: No the entities will become post params.. to add get params just add in the url..

Comment: Or if you want to use a better way, you'd need to use `Uri.Builder`

Comment: I will try your answer now

Comment: I got this <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
        <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
        <p>Severity: Warning</p>
        <p>Message:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given</p>
        <p>Filename: controllers/mobservice.php</p>
        <p>Line Number: 1436</p>
        </div>

Comment: You told me you are expecting authparams param as array, while the code says you want it string, thats why I asked.. how are you using the token and action in php?

Comment: i don't know, I only have API. And i shoult to store that data to server. I think it can be the same way with authparams